# FFmpeg: why avcodec_receive_frame need additional packet to get an I frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to FFmpeg. When learn it with the nice repo(https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial)，in the hello_world example I find avcodec_receive_frame dosen't return the first I frame until it gets the third packet, as following screenshot shows:
[image]
I'm wondering why additional packets are needed to receive an I frame.

Comment: This is probably an h264 video. Do you know what the GOP is?

Comment: @thekamilz Group of Pictures, or the distance between two I-frame. But i have no idea about the relation between GOP and the 'late' I-frame

Answer (score 1):

Most modern video codecs are using I/P/B frames which brings the decoding time stamp (DTS) and presentation time stamp (PTS). So, what hello_world does with ffmpeg's lib is the following:-

1. Demuxing (av_read_frame)

- Demuxes packets based on file format (mp4/avi/mkv etc.) until you have a packet for the stream that you want (eg. video) - (We might could say NAL units as an example here - not sure)

2. Feeds the decoder with the packet (avcodec_send_packet)

- Starts the decoding process until it has enough packets to give you the first frame (decodes based on DTS)

3. Checks whether a frame is ready to be presented (avcodec_receive_frame)

- Asks the decoder if it has a frame to be presented after feeding it. It might not be ready and you need to re-feed it or even it might give you more than 1 frames at once. (Frames comes out based on PTS)